# Audit trail for established Access database

Tags: ms-access-2010, audit, audit-trail

Good Evening all

I have inherited an Access database that is now running on Access 2010, there is currently no Audit trail for this dB and it's quite important that it has one.

I've read various articles that suggest a fairly neat solution based on calling a code module on an update event. However this involves editing every field in the dB to add a tagged property. The database isn't massive compared to some but going through maybe a hundred forms with between 5 and 50 fields on these form. Is there a method by which I could tag all the fields at once or maybe even another methodology

I was thinking of building a form users can fill in then an administrator does whatever is required at table level fills in their part of the same form, the data being appended to an audit trail table, seems a fairly unsatisfactory solution if this could be taken care of automatically ?

Any ideas

Comment: Have you investigated using "After Insert/Update/Delete" [data macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) on the tables? Have you also considered that any such audit trail will be subject to the security limitations inherent in Access databases? (In other words, if the audit trail really needs to be secure then an Access database file is not a suitable back-end to use.)

Comment: Yes I've considred that but as I say I've inherited this particular dB and a few others besides, I'm hoping for a short term fix that won't involve me attempting to modify every field on every form in every dB.

Comment: I'm hoping to eventually move all our databases onto a more suitable platform but thats a job for the future.